# What is the most energy efficient way to use a solar hot water electric booster?

Tags: energy

Thinking on the physics concepts involved in going from cool temperature to shower friendly hot with an electric booster in winter what would be more energy efficient and thus more economical? To run the electric water heater booster continously over winter or to turn it on for half an hour prior to use?

Its a bit hard to be able to break down the electric bill as its just given as overall total cost but my dads thinking we should run and experiment of going by on when needed instead of running it continuous.

Am I right to think of it in the analogy of it being more energy efficient running a car at a cruising constant speed then going on a stop start drive? Would it not by conceept be the same as forcing an engine to go from low to high to low to high and burning more fuel then to maintain a set speed?

In terms of kilowatts per hour or work or just a plain answer idc basic internet research is just telling me what specific system is better, idk what solar water heating or electric booster this rental is running on.

Comment: you dad is right, you won't be sure unless you do the experiment.

Answer (score 0):

It is my understanding that you can now buy small electric water heaters to be installed in the bathroom (or kitchen) which heat water on demand (which eliminates losses from a tank or long piping).

Answer (score 0):

An electrical device that heats only the water that is being used must be more economical. When a boiler is electricaly heated for half an hour, it is common that only part of the heated water is used during the shower, and the remaining is slowly cooled inside it afterwards. It is a waste of energy.

But the quality of a shower from the boiler is superior, because there is no limitation of flow. The water is already heated. Besides that, the boiler can use solar energy. Depending on the local climate, it is enough a couple of hours of sun to have warm water for the day. My experience is with a 200 l boiler with solar panels. I guess that only 5% of the days it is necessary to turn on the electrical heater. But it is not automatic. In the case of several days without sun, it is better to turn the electricity on some time before each shower. Otherwise, even for a good isolation, energy is lost to the environment.